# Record screen using Adobe products

Tags: video, adobe, screen-recording

I have a premium Adobe account.  What product should I use to make a screen record?

Or what free program on Mac has the same functionality?

Comment: If you use win10 i would recommend the inbuilt screen recording `WIN+G`.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Captivate is the tool you can use from Adobe